# Replace first occurrence with one value and second with another

Tags: javascript

Giving this original string...

```
Test text _with bold_ and perhaps one another text _with bold in the same string_.
```

... how to efficiently replace the first occurrence of " _ " with "< b >" and the second occurrence " _ " with "< /b >" to achieve the following result:

```
Test text <b>with bold</b> and perhaps one more text <b>with bold in the same string</b>.
```

**Note:** I have an array of hundreds of those strings that will need to go through this process in order to render in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for this.

The replace-pattern is the following:

`_(.*?)_` with the flag `g` at the end - so it will replace until all occurances are satisfied.

The `?` in the regex says it will stop matching at the first `_` afert the opening `_` (non-greedy).

`<b>$1</b>` says replace the matched string with this. Where the `$1` refers to the content matched in the brackets `()`

```js
var text = "This is _bold text_ and here _some more_";
var text_replaced = text.replace(/_(.*?)_/g, '<b>$1</b>');

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text_replaced;
```

```html
<span id="result" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a while loop which checks if there any more underscores in the text and replaces them, assuming that there must be an even number of "_" in the text:

```
var test = "text _with bold_ and perhaps one another text _with bold in the same string_.";
b_index = test.indexOf("_");

while (b_index != -1) {
  test = test.replace("_", "<b>");
  test = test.replace("_",  "</b>");
  b_index = test.indexOf("_");
}
```

After the while loop, you can assign the innerHTML of whichever element you wish to the variable test.